# What makes an estimate "conservative?"

Tags: word-usage

When estimating (time, for example), it's common to either ask for or offer a "conservative" estimate. Irrespective of political connotations, how does "conservative" describe a given estimate?

Is a conservative estimate the one the causes the least disruption, regardless of whether the estimate is an overestimate or an underestimate?

Comment: ...or "liberal" for that matter.

Comment: In such contexts, ***conservative*** means something more like *cautious, non-optimistic*. Which usually means any scalar value cited in a conservative estimate is likely to be *lower* than most other estimates. But  presumably there can be contexts where the conservative approach leads to a *higher* estimated value for something than other predictions.

Comment: ^^ this is the best answer so far ;-)

Comment: Yes to what @FumbleFingers said, and will add that the reason as estimate would want to be "conservative" is usually so the recipient of the estimate would be prepared for a "worst case scenario". (The numeric swing and direction of what conservative means is totally contextual to the thing being discussed.)

Comment: A conservative estimate protects (or conserves) your side's bottom line or reputation for execution.

Comment: If you are trying to get someone to pay for something, and give them a conservative estimate, you are not giving them what the actual cost will be in the end. conservative+ less than what is usually expected.

Answer (score 3):

The [dictionary definition of 'conservative estimate'](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/conservative_1) is one which is **deliberately intended to be lower than what the real value actually is**.

In the case you mention, where a high estimate is the one that involves the least risk, you could reasonably argue for describing it as conservative, but you will be going against established usage and run the risk of being misunderstood. I would recommend looking for another word in this case - perhaps 'safe'.

Comment: I'm not looking for a particular word. I'm looking to understand this one. It's difficult to conclude because the OED says: "Characterized by caution or moderation; (esp. of an estimate) purposely low **for the sake of caution.**" So I'm trying to work out if it's the smallness that makes it conservative, or the caution that makes it conservative.

Comment: If you ask me how long it will take me too build a shed and I think it will take 1 week, so I tell you 2 weeks - that seems like a conservative estimate to me.

Comment: The definition does not depend on the value being lower or higher.  Whether the value is higher or lower depends on context.

Answer (score 3):

What FF said -- a conservative estimate is the least risky, given whatever criteria for "risk" exist.  As such, it may be less apt to "grab opportunity".

Eg, if I'm operating a Christmas tree lot I generally need to order all of the trees from the tree farm before the season starts, and before I have a good idea of what the market for trees will be this year.  A conservative estimate of potential sales would leave my lot empty at the end of the season (lost opportunity) while a liberal estimate would leave me with unsold trees at the end (with actual money lost since I still must pay the supplier for those trees).

Comment: +1 for relating "conservative" to risk rather than to guessing on the low or high side specifically. Whether it's underestimates or overestimates that are conservative depends on the context.

Comment: It seems to have moved from the sense "Characterized by caution or moderation" to a more specific idea "purposely low for the sake of caution." (OED) This can be confusing because a low estimate isn't necessarily cautious (e.g. "We don't need many lifeboats on this ocean liner" wouldn't be conservative.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that a "conservative" estimate means the absolute minimum number a quantity could be.

A "liberal" estimate would be the maximum quantity if you factored in every assumption that could potentially increase it.

I think an example might be, if you are counting widgits, and there were some things that might be widgits or might not, a conservative estimate would exclude them, and a liberal estimate would include them.

Answer (score 0):

To be conservative with an estimate is to wish to **avoid underestimating**, while to be liberal is to want to **avoid overestimating**.

So, if you were in a position of giving an estimate, you look at the consequences of underestimating or overestimating.  For example if you were an employee of a company, and your boss says "How long will it take you to do X?", you might think:

"If i **underestimate** the necessary time, i'm going to end up delivering it late, and look bad.  On the other hand, if I **overestimate** the time my boss will probably just say "Ok" and put that in the planning schedule, then later I get to deliver it earlier than expected and look cool."

So, there's bad consequences for underestimating, and no bad consequences for overestimating.  So, you would **overestimate**, and you would call that a **conservative estimate**.

If you were a freelancer, there's also potentially bad consequences for overestimating:  they might give the job to someone cheaper.  So, you need to balance the two potential problems.  If you were really desperate for the work, and willing to take a risk on having to work nights or something, you might give a **liberal estimate** - a cheap one in this case.

So, logically, a conservative estimate is one where you deliberately overestimate the resources (time, money, materials etc), and a liberal estimate is one where you deliberately underestimate the resources (perhaps because you think it's going to be easy, and you want to make sure the client gives you the job).

Comment: I could accept the statement that "To be conservative...is to...avoid underestimating" but I'm not sure about the explanation. Is a "conservative" estimate conservative *because* there are fewer bad consequences for it? Therefore, if UNDERestimating had the least-negative consequences, would it become the "conservative" estimate? I'm just not sure I follow the explanation well...

Comment: I've never heard of a "liberal estimate".  The reverse of a conservative estimate could be an "aggressive estimate", "stretch goal" or similar marker that the estimate has a risk of not being met.

Comment: A conservative estimate is usually a low one, i.e. one that wants to avoid overestimating. http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/conservative_1

Comment: [The truth is that, **at a conservative estimate,** there are only about eighty thousand South Asian nationals (in Kenya).](http://www.awaazmagazine.com/previous/index.php/archives/item/109-living-in-constitutional-times) It seems pretty clear the writer there suspects the *true* value is in fact lower than his conservative estimate.

Comment: @mHurley A conservative estimate is one where you **deliberately**, knowingly overestimate.  The stuff about consequences just explains the **motivation for the decision to make a conservative estimate**.

Answer (score 0):

A conservative estimate is a 'guess' on the lower side of given parameters, based on knowledge and experience.
I'll use the analogy of an auction valuation. If the valuer believes the item in question may achieve a bid of between, let's say 10k to 15k, the conservative end of his valuation is 10k. The item may, if the right under bidder is present achieve much more, or, maybe not even reach it's reserve. It's an estimate.
I reiterate, a conservative estimate is a 'guess' based on knowledge and experience

Comment: I don't agree that "a conservative estimate is a 'guess' based on knowledge and experience".

Answer (score 0):

Conservative

Adj - Less risky (conservative estimate), Less wasteful (conservative consumption)
Noun - A person disposed to conservative actions / choices.

Comment: Can you expand on the dictionary lookup to help the requestor?

Comment: The OP didn't ask about "conservative" in general, but the phrase "conservative estimate" quite specifically. And it's clear from his other comments that he's read the dictionary definition already, and anyway a question which can be conclusively answered by looking the word asked about in a dictionary is not a good question and should not be answered. We are not here to reprint the dictionary. In other words: this  answer is just noise, and adds no value.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old thread, I found it because we're remodeling a house and got into a disagreement. She thinks a "conservative estimate" is intentionally high, because if you come in at that number, it's fine, if you come in under, it's even better. But when I see the term "conservative estimate" I think it is intentionally low; the minimum cost/number.

But as a lawyer, I think the phrase is intentionally ambiguous so, if the estimate is way off, you can explain the conflict away as a misunderstanding in terminology.

This is one of those situations where plain language should be used (just ask what's the most/least it will cost?) or where one should ask for clarification so there's no misunderstandings down the road.

Comment: A conservative estimate is simply a cautious one. If you are remodeling and the contractor gives you a conservative estimate of the cost, it is one that will be somewhat high. If you provide the contractor a conservative estimate of the budget, it is one that will be somewhat low. There is no ambiguity to be had.

Comment: There is ambiguity in some cases. If you look in the OED there are two slightly different meanings for "conservative":  "Characterized by caution or moderation" and "purposely low for the sake of caution." If an estimate is high for the sake of caution it meets one definition but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Given the ambiguity around “conservative”, I typically use “optimistic” and “pessimistic” to differentiate lower and upper range of estimates respectively.

Comment: This doesn't work; it depends on whether a high statistic is better. "An optimistic estimate is that 80% of adults will have been double-jabbed by October" means that it's probably going to be less than this. "An optimistic estimate is that the R number will be 1" means that the actual figure could well be or rise to over 1.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience (estimating construction build costs for large infrastructure projects), a conservative estimate is in fact the estimate which is most pessimistic (I.e. the higher value which includes the most risk). Which is why the dictionary definition threw me.

Then reading the comments (with one person using the example of an auction) I did wonder whether in fact (in the context of an auctioneers valuation or a house valuation for example) a conservative estimate in this sense is the lower value that you would achieve at auction (i.e. also the most pessimistic view)?

Comment: There's a difference between 'exposes the company giving a firm estimate to the risk of losing money on the contract by  not being circumspect' and 'is most rigorous in perceiving different sources of risk'.

Answer (score 0):

A conservative estimate is one that is cautious or non-optimistic or that requires the fewest assumptions or expectations.

Whether a conservative estimate is over or under depends on the context.  For example, the sentence, "2500 soldiers is a conservative estimate", means that *fewer* are expected to take a castle because you can expect the castle to be taken with more (i.e. the 2500 in this case).

We can see the optimism aspect come into play if we are discussing casualties.  If we are on the defeated side, we expect, and are optimistic, that the number is lower.  Therefore 2500 is pessimistic.  The opposite is true of the victorious side (if they have to fight their foes again).